# AutoMapper is Creating Duplicate Record in DB

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, poco

It could be very basic question but i have stuck with this

I have an Entity Structure like this one below

```
  public class OrderTagGroup : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderTag> OrderTags { get; set; }
}

 public class OrderTag : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int? OrderTagGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

and Its respective DTO is

```
public class OrderTagGroupDto : EntityDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public List<OrderTagDto> OrderTags { get; set; }
}

public class OrderTagDto : EntityDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int? OrderTagGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

I have added the Auto mapping as well like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderTagGroup, OrderTagGroupDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderTagGroupDto, OrderTagGroup>();

Mapper.CreateMap<OrderTag, OrderTagDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderTagDto, OrderTag>();
```

Here is my Repository update

```
public void UpdateOrderTagGroup(OrderTagGroupDto OrderTagGroup)
    {
        var group = _OrderTagGroupRepo.Get(OrderTagGroup.Id);
        if (group != null && group.Id > 0)
        {
            Mapper.Map<OrderTagGroupDto, OrderTagGroup>(OrderTagGroup,group);

        }
    }
```

My Question is, whenever my OrderTagGroupDTO goes for the update, it creates a new row in the DB and previous entry is not deleted.

Could you please help me where i am wrong ?

Answer (score -4):

Automapper is for entity->DTO ..

NEVER use automapper or similar for DTO->entity it's NOT designed for that

For DTO->entity you should 'always' do it 'manually'